# what is the difference between normal js timers and this jquery timers plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, timer

If I use setInterval or setTimeout for an animation, the speed of the animation is different in all the browsers, but if I use the jquery timer plugin its the speed is almost exactly the same in every browser.
How exactly does it do that? ive looked through the code of the plugin but i cant figure it out.
Here is the link for the plugin [jquery.timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

Comment: Wow, someone actually implemented stopTime()!

Answer (score 2):

Not likely.

This is at the heart of the [plugin](http://jquery.offput.ca/js/jquery.timers.js)

```
if (!element.$timers[label][fn.$timerID]) 
  element.$timers[label][fn.$timerID] = window.setInterval(handler,interval);
.
.
.
window.clearInterval(timers[label][fn.$timerID]);
```